# While generating test coverage jenkins sends me errors and does not generate the folder or file

Tags: maven, jenkins

I generated this error: coverage results were found using the pattern '**/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml 
here is my pom.xml

```xml
<pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>sonar-maven.plugin</artifactId>
             <version>
            2.5
             </version>
           </plugin>

    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
         <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>

         </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin </artifactId>
            <configuration >
                <formats >
            <format> xml </format>
            <format>html</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>coverage</goal>
                        </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>
     </plugin>

   </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Am I wrong or is the error in the handle part?

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

> Could not find goal 'coverage' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6 among available goals cobertura, instrument, clean, check, help, dump-datafile -> [Help 1]

Use this :

```xml
<project>
....
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
   </build>
...
</project>
```

Comment: try to trim space in this : <format> xml </format>  <format>xml</format>